# Trouble catching exceptions occurring through 3rd party library deep in call stack

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-requests

I am using an API to collect a lot of statistics of a website, but the website limits the rate at which I can pull data from the server by closing my connection once I reach this rate (usually raising a `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError`, but sometimes raising other connection related errors like time outs).

How I've tried to solve this is by building a wrapper around the 3rd party library function that is opening the connection and pulling the data. The function `try_request()` is below, but essentially each time this function is called, I use a try statement to see if I can pull the data, and an except clause to catch any exception, wait 5 seconds, and recursively try again (for 5 tries). The issue is that it doesn't seem to be catching the exception.

PS The "while True" statement is just to spam the website for a second to get the error... I know this isn't a good idea in practice

```py
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import *
from nba_api.stats.static import players
from nba_api_helpers import try_request

active_players = players.get_active_players()

for player in active_players:

    if player['full_name'] == 'Stephen Curry':
        while True:
            dummy = try_request(commonplayerinfo.CommonPlayerInfo(player['id']))
            print('success')
```

and the `try_request()` function which is in a different file:

```py
def try_request(api_call, number_tries=5):
    sleep_time = 5
    tries_left = number_tries

    if tries_left == 1:
        print("Final try...")
        return api_call
    else:
        try:
            api_call
        except:
            print("Caught exception in Endpoint request... Waiting {} seconds to try again".format(sleep_time))
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
            try_request(api_call, tries_left-1)
```

If I put a try/except around the top level code like below, it catches an exception, but this is not what I'm trying to do because I need to retry the function that failed.

Here is an example of the error code I often get... I would thought this would have been caught in the except clause of my `try_request()` function, but it's not getting picked up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\http\client.py", line 1321, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\http\client.py", line 296, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\http\client.py", line 257, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\ssl.py", line 1052, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\ssl.py", line 911, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 367, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=read_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 306, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self, url, "Read timed out. (read timeout=%s)" % timeout_value)
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stats.nba.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=30)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jaked/PycharmProjects/NBA/src/classes/scratch.py", line 13, in <module>
    dummy = try_request1(commonplayerinfo.CommonPlayerInfo(player['id']))
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nba_api\stats\endpoints\commonplayerinfo.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.get_request()
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nba_api\stats\endpoints\commonplayerinfo.py", line 40, in get_request
    timeout=self.timeout,
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nba_api\library\http.py", line 123, in send_api_request
    response = requests.get(url=base_url, params=parameters, headers=request_headers, proxies=proxies, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 524, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 637, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 529, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stats.nba.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=30)
```

Thanks and looking forward to learning!

Answer (score 0):

I do NOT recomend using a recursive strategy like you are doing. Have you tried a loop instead? Maybe something like this:

```
def try_request(api_call_function, number_tries=5, sleep_seconds=5):
    for i in range(number_tries):
        try:
            return api_call_function()
        except Exception as ex:
            print('try', i)
            print(ex)

        time.sleep(sleep_seconds)

    # choose a default return value for the case when the API call
    # failed the max number of tries
    return None
```

And try to catch a explicit exception class and print in so you can see what type of errors are raised. An empty `except` clause (like you showed in the question) has the danger of hiding other errors that might ocurr.

Does this help you?

---

After you edited the error stacktrace into your question, I noticed that your `try_request()` function does not seem to get called, because it does not appear in your stacktrace (notice how it goes from the file `C:/Users/jaked/PycharmProjects/NBA/src/classes/scratch.py` directly to the 3rd-party NBA lib `C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nba_api\stats\endpoints\commonplayerinfo.py`).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jaked/PycharmProjects/NBA/src/classes/scratch.py", line 13, in <module>
    dummy = try_request1(commonplayerinfo.CommonPlayerInfo(player['id']))
  File "C:\Users\jaked\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nba_api\stats\endpoints\commonplayerinfo.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.get_request()
```

Are you sure that this is an error stacktrace from when you used your function `try_request()`? Because something seems to be off here.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the issue of recursion?

I've tried implementing a loop as you've suggested, but the same thing occurs. I'm OK with the empty except clause (that just means it catches every exception right??) because I'd like to first demonstrate that I've coded this try_request function properly--it doesn't even seem like that is correct. Then once I can get this to catch an exception, I'll get more specific

Comment: @jakedaly recursion adds memory and processing overhead, because a new function call has to be added to the [execution stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). Recursion has its use cases, but in your case this overhead is unnecessary as it adds no more value than a regular loop. Using recursion in your code is not an error, I just made an improvement suggestion.

Comment: @jakedaly Your `try ... except` should catch the errors if they originate inside the `api_call` that is inside the `try`. Could you add the full error stacktrace to your question so we can see where exactly these errors are raised? Maybe they originate somewhere else?

Comment: @Ralf-- Because I use the 3rd party function call as an input to the try_request() function, is it possible that this third party function is getting evaluated before the try_request() function get's evaluated? In other words, is Python evaluating the expression at the input of my try_request function before it evaluates the function itself??